# How do I view a Variant Call Format file on a Macbook Air with Intel processor?

Tags: macos, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm a high school kid doing a bioinformatics project but I can't seem to find software that allows me to view a Variant Call Format file without corrupting the data. If I had a Windows computer I would've used MobaXTerm to view it, but that's not available on macOS so...

Anyone knows of software to view the VCF file properly, and can share the commands to view the VCF file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't a VCF just a text file? Perhaps it's compressed and that's why keeps coming up garbled?

Answer (score 0):

MobaXTerm allow you to have a Linux system in your window computer. In a Mac computer, you do not need that. Use the terminal as you did with MobaXTerm